# Updating object in core data causes app to crash

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

I am fairly new at core data and am having a problem. My app currently is quite simple. I have a list of users with a username and an email. The app launched and pulls all the users from the local database via core data NSFetchedRequest. The app currently can create, read, and delete with no errors. I followed the apple tutorial on core data.

The problem I am having is saving an editted user. When clicking on the user, the edit view controller is shown where the person can edit the username and email of that particular user. When I go to update and save the user, the app crashes. The error is:

> 2012-04-09 17:47:09.757 SEA[7032:fb03] CoreData: error: Serious application error.  Exception was caught during Core Data change processing.  This is usually a bug within an observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.  [ valueForUndefinedKey:]: the entity User is not key value coding-compliant for the key "timeStamp". with userInfo {
>       NSTargetObjectUserInfoKey = " (entity: User; id: 0x880ec10  ; data: {\n    email = \"sampleUser@gmail.com\";\n    username = sampleUser1;\n})";
>       NSUnknownUserInfoKey = timeStamp;
>   }
>   2012-04-09 17:47:09.760 SEA[7032:fb03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ valueForUndefinedKey:]: the entity User is not key value coding-compliant for the key "timeStamp".'

From the looks of the error, its still seeing the attribute timeStamp even though I deleted that attributed.
The user entity is like to following:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>


@interface User : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * username;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * email;

@end
```

If someone could please help me I would truly appreciate it.

Comment: Show us your data model file.

Comment: My data model file consists if a single entity: User, with username:string and email:string as the attributes. That is all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have just edited the Apple sample code is there any mention to updating a property called `timeStamp`.

Do a project wide search for `timeStamp` and update as appropriate (e.g. remove any mention as you are not using it in your model)

Comment: Oh your a life saver! There was a call to configureWithCell in the MasterViewController that was using the key timeStamp. I didn't think to look in there because I was not using that controller anywhere but some default code was calling that view controller. Thanks again.